# Modifying turn.js jquery to load faster

Tags: jquery

I am using the turn.js jquery plugin with a large jpg image sequence to add flipbook effects.

my question is that if there's any way to create some sort of "loader" or allow it to load in chunks and start playing after a certain amount of images are loaded.

Currently when i open this page all the images are loaded that take too much time, so this is not good for my users. i want to load first 4 images are loaded first and animation is start and when user turn this 4 images the other 4 images are load and this process continue at last image,

Please help me !

Thank you very much